# Magento product search very slow

Tags: magento

We are working on a Diamond search engine. We  have used Magento default query function to search from about 75K diamond records, But search query is very slow.

http://bahdos.com/diamond/round.html

Any suggestions to make it faster?

Comment: that's a lot of products, do you have a decent server spec? Optimize MySQL and you can get big gains. Magento is never going to work great with a poor spec machine, no matter what you do.

Comment: Are you on ce or ee version?

Comment: what server config are best suited. I am planning to change the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We upgraded the server. Had web server and mysql server separated . It solved the problem

Comment: Hi. Can you let us know what kind of server specs 'before' and 'after' we are talking about? I believe this kind of reference would help a lot with comparing our own server abilities :).

Comment: I found amazon's tier list for EC2 giving a good view on what's needed for certain application dedicated servers: http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/ combine the specs with the use cases and it will give you a better view on what server specs you need for each type off application.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you install SOLR search.

This will increase your search speed.
Also make sure flat catalog is on.